# Pythons Pandas `from_dict` formating `to_csv`

Tags: python, pandas

Ive got a dictionary in the following format `key[0],key[1], value` im trying to put this dict into a DataFrame and then write this to a csv file. Now trying to work out how to format the DataFrame is causing me pains. Ive read the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) but i cant work out how to format the frame so that each row is as follows

```
column1  column2 column3
key[0]   key[1]  value
key[0]   key[1]  value
key[0]   key[1]  value
```

Affectivley id like to be able to carry out the following to create the formdata. I was using CsvWriter but I wanted for sort on the Key[0] when writing to the Csv so thought pandas would be a simple answer :P, and here we are lol

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    print key[0],key[1], value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily construct a pandas data frame from a list of tuples.

```
d = {(0,1): 'a', (0,2): 'b', (1,2): 'c'}

data = [(k1,k2,v) for (k1,k2),v in d.items()]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['key1', 'key2', 'value'])
df
```

Outputs:

```
  key1 key2 value
0   0   1   a
1   1   2   c
2   0   2   b
```

Then to write to a csv:

```
df.to_csv('filePath')
```

Comment: Arr ok makes perfect sense. Where would the sorting on the first column come in? During the DF creation or at the writing of the csv?

Comment: @iNoob, you can do it in between the data frames creation and writing to file with `df = df.sort_values(by=['key1','key2'])`

Comment: I just worked it out went with `df.sort_values('Key1', ascending=True, inplace=True)`

Comment: @iNoob that works too. Please mark this question as closed if it is answered